# function typedef declarator - default parameter positions

Tags: c++, function, parameters, typedef, default-parameters

My understanding of function declarations has always been that default value parameters are declared **after** non default value parameters.

But I just noticed that I'm able to typedef a function declaration that breaks this rule:

```
  typedef           // type of "int my_function ( int=1 , int )"
  int               // return type
  ( t_func_ptr )    // function type name
  ( int = 1         // arg0, default value - declared before non-default
  , int             // arg1
  ) ;

  /*
  // this wont compile, so why be able to typedef it?
  int my_bad_function ( int=1 , int )
  {
  } ;
  */
```

I'm curious to know why the typedef is possible?

EDIT: I compiled with a range of compilers (I'm using a cross target IDE), not sure about the underlying compiler versions, need to check, but the targets are for windows (mingw), linux ubuntu, avr, arduino (atmega, due, uno), raspberrypi, microchip (chipkit),etc. – Michael Collier 2 hours ago

- `i686-w64-mingw32-g++ (GCC) 4.8.2`
- `g++ (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3) 4.8.4`
- `avr-g++ (GCC) 4.8.1`
- `arm-none-eabi-g++ (GNU Tools for ARM Embedded Processors)
  4.8.3 20140228 (release) [ARM/embedded-4_8-branch revision 208322]`
- `pic32-g++ (chipKIT) 4.5.1 chipKIT Compiler for PIC32 MCUs v1.31-20120614`
- `arm-none-eabi-g++ (GNU Tools for ARM Embedded Processors) 4.7.4 20130913 (release) [ARM/embedded-4_7-branch revision 202601]`
- `msp430-g++ (MSPGCC 20120406 (With patches: sf3540953 sf3559978))`
- `4.6.3 20120301 (mspgcc LTS 20120406 unpatched)`
- `arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ (crosstool-NG 1.17.0) 4.7.2`

Comment: What compiler are you using? Which version of it? My compiler (recent clang trunc) does not allow it.

Comment: Could this be undefined behavior (again)?

Comment: g++ v4.9.3 spits out the compilation with "error: default arguments are only permitted for function parameters" - not only that it doesn't accept the bad order, but it doesn't accept parameters in func typedefs at all. So, what wretched compiler are you using?

Comment: I compiled with a range of compilers (I'm using a cross target IDE), not sure about the underlying compiler versions, need to check, but the targets are for windows (mingw), linux ubuntu, avr, arduino (atmega, due, uno), raspberrypi, microchip (chipkit),etc.

Comment: i686-w64-mingw32-g++ (GCC) 4.8.2
g++ (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3) 4.8.4
avr-g++ (GCC) 4.8.1
arm-none-eabi-g++ (GNU Tools for ARM Embedded Processors) 4.8.3 20140228 (release) [ARM/embedded-4_8-branch revision 208322]
pic32-g++ (chipKIT) 4.5.1 chipKIT Compiler for PIC32 MCUs v1.31-20120614
arm-none-eabi-g++ (GNU Tools for ARM Embedded Processors) 4.7.4 20130913 (release) [ARM/embedded-4_7-branch revision 202601]
msp430-g++ (MSPGCC 20120406 (With patches: sf3540953 sf3559978)) 4.6.3 20120301 (mspgcc LTS 20120406 unpatched)
arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ (crosstool-NG 1.17.0) 4.7.2

Comment: Sorry about the formatting, I'm learning how to use this page..

Comment: added various compiler release tested 
from comments

Comment: It is not possible to do; not `before` and not `later`, It is not logical to do. Whether in a simple function `int f( int=0, int ) or `typedef` function or `template` function.

Answer (score 2):

Default arguments are only allowed in the parameter lists of function declarations and lambda-expressions (since C++14) and are not allowed in the declarations of pointers to functions, references to functions, or in **typedef declarations** (e.g. see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_arguments).

g++ had issues when declaring function pointer types / non-pointer functions that accept default function parameters (see [bug 28262](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=28262) and [g++ v4.7.3](https://godbolt.org/g/StzJVG), [g++ v4.8.1](https://godbolt.org/g/m5PviB)).

The bug has been [fixed in version 4.9.0](https://godbolt.org/g/sDeqmR).

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to do; not **before** and not **later**.
**May be a bug in your version.**

### It is not logical to do.

Whether in a
 - simple function `int f( int=0, int )` or
 - typedef function or
 - template function

---

If default parameter is possible in the first place, then when the function is invoked, **complier gets ambiguous** what argument belongs to first place.